# ionic 3 tabs hardware back button won't exit

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have an ionic 3 app based on the [super template](https://github.com/ionic-team/starters/tree/master/ionic-angular/official/super). I have set the root page to the following:

```
<ion-tabs>
    <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" [tabTitle]="tab1Title" tabIcon="bonfire"></ion-tab>
    <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" [tabTitle]="tab2Title" tabIcon="search"></ion-tab>
    <ion-tab [root]="tab3Root" [tabTitle]="tab3Title" tabIcon="cog"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

When I press the hardware back button on this page, nothing happens at all. However, when I change the content to something else, like:

```
<p>Hello</p>
```

Then the hardware back button exits, as I would like.

How can I make the hardware back button work correctly on the tabbed page, while preserving the working default behaviour on other pages?

Comment: the default behaviour of tabs (any tabs page) once the stack is empty then it will close it will not move to the previous tabs

Comment: @MohanGopi my issue is that it never closes once the stack is empty. The back button does nothing once I'm on the tab page.

Comment: please comment all the registered back button action and then try you will get the default behaviour

Comment: @MohanGopi There are none. I searched the entire project for `registerBackButtonAction` and found no results

Comment: then there must be some other issue  why dont you try creating a new tabs project and simply install it in your device and check so that you will come to know what is the difference in back button action use this command to create project `ionic start myApp tabs` and deploye it in device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up needing to do this in `app.container.ts` to get the desired behaviour:

```
platform.registerBackButtonAction(() => {
    let nav = app.getActiveNav();
    let activeView = nav.getActive();
    if (activeView != null){
        if (nav.canGoBack()) {
           nav.pop();
        } else if (nav.parent.getSelected() != nav.parent.getByIndex(0)) {
            // goes to the first tab
            nav.parent.select(0);
        } else {
            platform.exitApp();
        }
     }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Inside your `app.component.ts` file

```
import { Nav, App } from 'ionic-angular';

export class MyApp {
@ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;
```

and then

```
         platform.registerBackButtonAction(() => {
           let nav = app.getActiveNav();
           let activeView: ViewController = nav.getActive();

           if(activeView != null){
             if(nav.canGoBack()) {

               nav.pop();
             }else if (typeof activeView.instance.backButtonAction === 'function')
             {
               activeView.instance.backButtonAction();
             }
             else {

               nav.parent.select(0); // goes to the first tab
             }
           }
         });
```

Hope this helps you and also don't forget to place it inside the platform.

in your respcted ts file where you need to close the application write  a funtion

```
backButtonAction(){
  this.platfrom.exitApp();
}
```

Comment: This helped me get where I needed to be, but it still didn't actually exit the app. See my answer for how I accomplished that https://stackoverflow.com/a/48195605/998251

Comment: inorder to exit the app just write funtion with named backButtonAction() in the home page and check it out it will exit the app

Answer (score 0):

In your Tabs Page try to Add `ionViewDidEnter` and try to append the following class as follows:

```
ionViewDidEnter() {
                   this.platform.registerBackButtonAction(() => {
                        this.platform.exitApp();
                   });
             }
```

Answer (score 0):

Write your code inside the ***constructor()*** from which page you  to leave.

**Home.ts**

```
 constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    private platform: Platform) {
    this.platform.registerBackButtonAction(()=>{
      this.platform.exitApp();
    });
  }
```